# Is it possible to convert a ByteArrayOutputStream to a InputStream?

Tags: java, type-conversion, pipe, java-7, bytearrayoutputstream

Is it possible to convert a ByteArrayOutputStream to a InputStream? I need it for `URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream()`.

I need this because I do want to avoid `new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())`, that make **two** new copies of the data.

I checked the javadoc of [`PipedInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html), and it seems it can be created only from a [`PipedOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html#write(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)).

I tried this

```
try (PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream()) {
    pos.write(bytes);
    
    try (InputStream is = new PipedInputStream(pos)) {
        contentType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    throw new IOUncheckedException(e);
}
```

But it gives to me

> java.io.IOException: Pipe not connected

Is it possible, maybe converting it in an intermediate `PipedOutputStream`, without creating a copy of the data?

Comment: Piped I/O (extra thread!) should give you an InputStream sitting on the ByteArrayOutputStream. Just adapt an example. Otherwise as you only need the bytes at the begin of the data, just make a copy of those bytes.

Comment: @JoopEggen `Piped I/O (extra thread!) should give you an InputStream sitting on the ByteArrayOutputStream. Just adapt an example` If I had an example I didn't asked :D

Comment: This has nothing to do with piped streams. Your big clue is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream(java.io.InputStream)): Parameters: is - an input stream that supports marks. If you're overriding that method, you can use BufferedInputStream, mark it and reset it once you've done your heuristics.

Comment: @user207421 this is what I want to avoid..... I updated the question

Comment: @g00se is absolutely correct. Wrap the `URLConnection`'s input stream in a `BufferedInputStream`, which you want to do anyway, and pass that to `guessContentTypeFromStream()`. It will mark it, guess the content type from the first few bytes, and then reset it so you can read the entire contents. This isn't clear from the Javadoc, but it is implied, and it does work. There are few if any useful uses for `PipedInput/OutputStream`. I've used them once in 25 years and the code didn't make it into production.

Comment: @user207421 How can I "wrap" into `BufferedInputStream` without two copies? Have you read the Slaw's answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68754926/1763602 Furthermore, since I read from a BAOS and not from a file, I think I don't need buffers

Comment: I do not understand your question. `new BufferedInputStream()` does not create two copies. The reason for using `BufferedInputStream` is that it supports mark/reset, which is required for `URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream()`. You don't need any more streams, buffers, pipes, whatever. Just get the input stream that you already have, whatever it is, wrap it in `BufferedInputStream()`, call `guessContentType()` with it, and then continue to use the `BufferedInputStream` in whatever way you are already using it. The answer by Slaw just creates another redundant class to do the same thing.

Comment: @user207421 I don't have an `InputStream`, I have a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, as written in title and question.

Comment: Where does the `ByteArrayOutputStream` come from? Does no possibility to replace it with a different `OutputStream` (e.g. the pipe end) *before* the data is written to it exist? Why?

Comment: @Holger: The creation of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` is in another method, so it can be called by some other method that does not need `PipedOutputStream`

Comment: So, is it possible to separate the creation of the `OutputStream` from the code that writes to it? So one caller could still create a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and pass it to the writing code whereas other code could pass a different `OutputStream` like a `PipedOutputStream`. I see the deleted answers suggested a subclass of `ByteArrayOutputStream`, which does already imply the possibility to alter the creation site.

Answer (score 3):

When you have the possibility to replace the `ByteArrayOutputStream` with a subclass, efficiently reading back is actually very easy:

```java
public class ReadableByteArrayOutputStream extends ByteArrayOutputStream {

    public ReadableByteArrayOutputStream() {
    }

    public ReadableByteArrayOutputStream(int size) {
        super(size);
    }

    public synchronized InputStream read() {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(buf, 0, count);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void reset() {
        buf = new byte[buf.length];
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

While `toArray()` would create a copy of the buffer, `ByteArrayInputStream`’s constructor does not copy the data but store the array reference. So it’s the most efficient way to read the data, supporting all bulk transfer methods, as well as `mark`/`reset`.

E.g.

```java
ReadableByteArrayOutputStream os = new ReadableByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
w.write("just some text");
w.flush();

System.out.println(new Scanner(os.read()).next());

InputStream is = os.read();
is.mark(9);
byte[] b = new byte[9];
new DataInputStream(is).readFully(b);
System.out.println(new String(b, "UTF-8"));

is.reset();
System.out.println(new String(new DataInputStream(is).readAllBytes(), "UTF-8"));
```

```
just
just some
just some text
```

The input stream returned by `read()` represents a snapshot of the data written so far, without being affected by subsequent writes. To ensure that the input stream stays consistent, the output stream’s `reset()` method has been overwritten, so this output stream will never overwrite previous data.

Comment: very ingenious!

Answer (score 0):

Even if this does not answer the question, I solved my problem using [mime-util](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/eu.medsea.mimeutil/mime-util):

```java
public class MyMimeUtil {
    static {
        MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector(
            "eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.MagicMimeMimeDetector"
        );
    }
    
    public static String getMime(byte[] bytes) {
        Collection<MimeType> mimeTypes = MimeUtil.getMimeTypes(bytes);
        MimeType mimeType = mimeTypes.iterator().next();
        String res = mimeType.toString();
        
        return res;
    }
}
```